# Is there any event for Chrome Extension Popup animation complete?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When you click the Chrome extension icon, there would be an [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867226/is-it-possible-to-customize-my-chrome-extension-popup-windows-opening-animation?noredirect=1#comment74780641_43867226).

Since it's not able to be disabled, is it possible to be listened as an event?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to listen animation stop event.

But listening for a resize event may be suitable for you:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

In my test the event was fired after ~35ms (`e.timeStamp`). It looks close to animation time.

Comment: Sounds interesting!